# How does "open user settings.json" start as

Tags: visual-studio-code

i am trying to make my own theme for VS code using the website themes.vscode.one however in the video showing how to take your theme into VS code but the file "open user settings.json" looks diffrent for me than it does in the video, does anyone know what it looks like?

for those wondering heres what it looks like for me:

```
{
    "Lua.telemetry.enable": true,
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/usr/bin/python3",
    "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnType": true
    },
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai"
}
```

ive tried to search online to find the original file, but i am unable to find it

Answer (score 0):

`settings.json` only contains your custom settings, so it starts as your configuration is already established.

You can modify it as shown in video you're watching, it should work as long as it's using the correct commands.

For more info on `settings.json`, please check [the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson).